# What R package to use to test assumptions for Structural Equation modelling?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, assumptions

I am looking for a way to test assumptions for Structural Equation Modelling. My model has observed variables that together predict one latent variable, which in turn predicts another observed variable. I looked at assumptions for regression but since the 'regressions' in this model contain a latent variable, there are no individual data values or residuals that can look at. I looked at `lavaan` and `semplot` packages, but these don't seem to include any way to test the model for assumptions. Can anyone point me in the right direction for which package to use, or how to go about this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to test the model for assumptions because factors are indeterminate functions of the data. Some workarounds exist, e.g.  Bollen, K. A., & Arminger, G. (1991). Observational residuals in factor analysis and structural equation models. Sociological methodology, 235-262.

Comment: That's what I thought, wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything. Many thanks for your answer and the reference!